# El código da como resultado 0 pero debe dar el resultado de perímetro y área

Tags: c

El código y ejercicio es el siguiente:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define PI 3.14159
#include "cabecera.h"
void mensajeMostrar();
double area0(double radio1);
float perimetro1(float perimetro1);
int main() {
    double parea1=0;
    int radio1=0;
    float perimetro1=0;
    printf ("introdusca el radio: ");
    scanf ("%ld",&radio1);
    printf ("el area es:%lf",parea1);
    printf("\n el perimetro es:%lf ",perimetro1);
    return 0;=
}
}
 void mensajeMostrar(){

}
 float perimetro1(float perimetro1){
     float radio1=0;
     perimetro1=2*PI*radio1;
     return perimetro1;
 
 }

double area0(double radio1){
    double area1=0;
    area1=PI*radio1*radio1;
    return area1;
}
```

> Sabiendo que el área de una circunferencia es A= Π * r 2
> y que el perímetro es P = 2*Π*r donde Π es el número Pi y r es el radio de la circunferencia.
> Realice un programa donde solicite el valor del radio y realice el cálculo tanto del área como del perímetro y muestre el resultado por pantalla.
> Defina variables para que contengan los valores de ambos resultados y para el
> valor de Pi emplee una constante.
> Cada uno de los cálculos, tanto del área como del perímetro, realícelos en dos funciones distintas, donde el valor del radio sea un argumento de las mismas.

Comment: la variable radio tambien debe ser float

Comment: No conozco mucho de C, pero a simple vista veo varios problemas ¿Tienes un módulo o librería llamado `cabecera.h`? En el `scanf` y en los `print` hay un `"%ld"` que [pudiera dar problemas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25860877/1545868) dependiendo del compilador. El `return 0;` tiene un signo de `=` que está de más. ¿Por qué la función `perimetro1` recibe como argumento la misma funcion (o al menos el mismo nombre)?

Answer (score 3):

Cualquier valor multiplicado por cero es cero:

```
float perimetro1(float perimetro1){
    float radio1=0;
    perimetro1=2*PI*radio1;
//                  ^^^^^^ <--- Esto es cero, al multiplicar todo valdrá cero.
    return perimetro1;
}
```

En la función anterior `radio1` es cero, y usas ese valor para multiplicar `2*PI` que, valgan lo que valgan tras multiplicarlos por `radio1` será cero. Por otro lado ¿Cómo es posible que una función que calcula el perímetro reciba el perímetro como argumento?, probablemente querías hacer esto:

```
float perimetro1(float radio1){
    float perimetro1=2*PI*radio1;
    return perimetro1;
}
```

O mejor aún, escribe menos código:

```
float perimetro1(float radio1) {
    return 2 * PI * radio1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema esta en que estas pasando mal las variables a las funciones. Dentro de las función perimetro1 estas asignando a la variable radio1 el valor 0, por lo que queda perimetro1=2*3.14159*0, lo que da 0. Pasa lo mismo en la función area0.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define PI 3.14159
#include "cabecera.h"
void mensajeMostrar();
double area0(double radio1);
float perimetro(float perimetro1);
int main() {
    double parea1=0;
    int radio1=0;
    float perimetro1=0;
    printf ("introdusca el radio: ");
    scanf ("%ld",&radio1);
    parea1 = area0(radio1);
    printf ("el area es:%lf",parea1);
    perimetro1 = perimetro(radio1);
    printf("\n el perimetro es:%lf ",perimetro1);
    return 0;
}

 float perimetro(float radio1){
     float radio1=0;
     perimetro1=2*PI*radio1;
     return perimetro1;
 
 }

double area0(double radio1){
    double area1=0;
    area1=PI*radio1*radio1;
    return area1;
}
```

He realizado alguna modificación, ya que a la funcion de perimetro no le estas pasando el argumento correcto, le pasas perimetro cuando tienes que pasarle radio. Ademas, he añadido la llamada a las funciones desde el main, ya que si no les llamas no devolverán el valor wque le pones en el return. Espero haberte ayudado.